# Swift Array: subscript with IndexPath - unable to mutate

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, collections, subscript

I'd like to add an extension to array of arrays to retrieve an `Element` with the *IndexPath* of size 2:

```
let array: [[String]] =  ....
let indexPath = IndexPath(indexes: [0, 0])
let string = array[indexPath]
```

I'm getting an error *cannot assign through subscript subscript is get-only* while implementing the following extension:

```
extension Array where Element : Collection, Element.Index == Int {
  subscript(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Element.Iterator.Element {
    get {
      return self[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
    }
    set {
      self[indexPath.section][indexPath.item] = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

What is the reason for such an error? How can I add a mutation option to the  *subscript*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to mutate the nested arrays you have to require that

```
Element : MutableCollection
```

instead of `Element : Collection`.

You can also define two extensions: a read-only subscript for read-only
collections, and a read-write subscript for mutable collections:

```
extension Collection where Index == Int, Element : Collection, Element.Index == Int {
    subscript(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Element.Iterator.Element {
        return self[indexPath[0]][indexPath[1]]
    }
}

extension MutableCollection where Index == Int, Element : MutableCollection, Element.Index == Int {
    subscript(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Element.Iterator.Element {
        get {
            return self[indexPath[0]][indexPath[1]]
        }
        set {
            self[indexPath[0]][indexPath[1]] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```